# How to disable Projekktor Video Player context menu & show default menu for html5 video player

Tags: html, video

I am using Projekktor Video Player to show videos for one of my web projects.

[Link to player site](http://www.projekktor.com/)

The player is good with flash fallback for older browsers.

There is one problem with this player (for some users this might not be a problem) but player script has over-ridden mouse right click function to show their own context menu.

I have tried to search this in their script file but did not succeed.

Can anyone help me out in this situation.

[Link to my one of video pages](http://gc.digitalinfobytes.com/Machines/rhino-machine/videos.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The context-menu is a implemented as a player plugin. You can easily deactivate it by overwriting the "plugins" config defaults, e.g.:

```
projekktor('<yourid>', {
    ... your config ...
    plugins: ['Display', 'Controlbar']
});
```

That´s it. The mouse events however are fetched anyway. To get them again you need to add a listener to the player itself, e.g.:

```
var myClick = function(evt) {
    console.log(evt); 
}

projekktor('<yourstuff>', {
    ... your config ...
    plugins: ['Display', 'Controlbar']
}, function(player) {
    player.addListener('mousedown', myClick);
});
```

... or bind you own one to the player container.